# EF Core Entity Circular Reference

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I am using C#.net and ef core.  I have the models below. When I get my list of competitions, I want to only get my related user.  However, I am getting the User and all the User's competitions.  How can I achieve this?  I had to do the following to get my list of competitions to show:

```
.AddJsonOptions(opt => opt.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore)

public partial class Competition
{
    public int CompetitionId { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public User User { get; set; }
}

public partial class User
{

    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Competition> Competitions { get; set; }
}
```

I have an api that uses entity framework to make calls to my database using the models describe above.  The call in my api that causes the circular reference is the following:

```
    [Produces("application/json")]
    [Route("api/Competitions")]
    public class CompetitionsController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDBContext _context;

        public CompetitionsController(ApplicationDBContext  context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        // GET: api/Competitions
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<Competition> GetCompetitions()
        {
            //return _context.Competitions;
            return _context.Competitions
                .Include(u => u.User).ToList();
        }
    }
```

Below is my onmodelcreating code block in my ApplicationDBContext class:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Competition>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.CompetitionId);

            entity.HasOne(d => d.User)
                .WithMany(p => p.Competitions)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.UserId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                .HasConstraintName("FK_Competitions_Users");
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<User>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.UserId);

            entity.HasIndex(e => e.UserName)
                .HasName("UC_UserName")
                .IsUnique();

            entity.Property(e => e.Email)
                .HasMaxLength(40)
                .IsUnicode(false);

            entity.Property(e => e.UserName)
                .HasMaxLength(40)
                .IsUnicode(false);
        });
    }
```

Comment: There's no obvious reason that should happen based on the code you have posted.  Please add to your question a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 4):

Old question, but in case someone still looking.
One solution is:

```
    services.AddMvc()
    .AddJsonOptions(options => {
        options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have ignored Competitions collection in user model while building.

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .Ignore(b => b.Competitions);
```

Comment: But then the collection can *never* be used in a LINQ query. I wonder if that's what they really want.

Comment: In this case he is concerned about getting Competitions.. returning list of competitions, each have user.. thats ok.. but what is the purpose of again binding list of competitions for that user.. if so it will go on loop...

Comment: On this particular path where I'm getting a list of competitions, I do indeed only want the details and relationships for the competition.  However, in other areas I want to retrieve user competitions.  Therefore, as far as I understand I would need to have the the list of competitions by user.