# Circular Reference with Include in .NET Core

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, circular-reference

I am using code like below in .NET core

```
.Include(p => p.Company).ThenInclude(p => p.Country).ToList();
```

My classes look like below,

```
 public partial class Company
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual Country Country { get; set; }
    }

     public partial class Country
    {
      public Country()
        {

            Companies = new HashSet<Company>();
        }

        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
         public string ShortCode { get; set; }

          public virtual ICollection<Company> Companies { get; set; }
    }
```

And I want only Company and then Country in side the company to be populated. But I am getting the Company inside the Country and then Country in those Companies and so on populated which is causing the response delayed.

I have already tried difference examples of Include on Google/StackOverFlow.

Comment: Please use the *correct* tags and mention the EF Core version you use. `Include()` is an EF Core method, not part of .NET Core or ASP.NET Core. Post your code too - what do the classes look like, how are the entities configured? `.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling` has nothing to do with EF Core, it's a JSON setting

Comment: You didn't post any configuration code. There are many questions about circular references like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52240008/ef-core-entity-circular-reference). This question shows the code that's needed - the classes, the configuration in `OnModelCreating` and the *actual* query, not just part of it.

Comment: Do you have lazy loading enabled on EF?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I would have added the configurations If there is something other than the standard. I have created models and context using scaffold and everything is pretty standard. Further thanks for pointing out the question, Its really relatable and almost same issue I am facing, but unfortunately that question does not have an accepted answer.

Comment: @RobertPerry Yes, It is as by default its true and I haven't changed the settings.

Comment: By default its actually disabled, you have to specifically enable it - which is why I asked

Comment: EF Core works that way, and it cannot be controlled. Moreover the EF Core itself has no issues with handling circular references. The actual problem is with serializers as mentioned in [Related data and serialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#related-data-and-serialization) documentation topic. If you need full control over what gets included, you shouldn't use entity classes and `Include` functionality, but DTO/ViewModel classes and projection (`Select`) queries.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't actually a problem. EF has what's called "object fix-up". Internally, it uses an object cache. When it builds entity instances for database query results, it adds those to the object cache, allowing it to then pull out those objects later, rather than issuing the same queries again.

Because of this object cache, if it already existing entity instances corresponding to a relationship, it will auto-fill that relationship from the object cache. It's not issuing a series of circular queries forever.

Comment: There is a way to disable this auto-fill in a relationship?

Comment: If you use `AsNoTracking()`, I believe it will prevent this behavior because the entities will not be added to the object cache in the first place. However, it's not reliable, as if you query anything without `AsNoTracking()` added, the entities in that query will go in the object cache, and will be fixed up. In other words, unless you control all the queries end-to-end, you can't guarantee fix-up won't occur at some point. That said, this is *desired* behavior. It makes EF more efficient. More likely than not, you're experiencing an XY problem, where you're thinking you should disable fix-up.

Comment: There's probably a better solution. For example, the problem in this question was related to circular references when serializing to JSON. The solution to that is to use a DTO and not the entity class directly. Then you can be explicit about what relationships are traversed during serialization.